# Reverse engineer a ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, xaml, workflow-foundation-4, controltemplate

Windows Workflow Foundation 4 contains a WPF property grid similar to the one available for Winforms. The toolbar up the top has a CLEAR button rather than the X shown by Visual Studio. This control has a ControlTemplate property that is not null at runtime. The template makes use of various glyphs for toolbar buttons.

Are there any tools or techniques that will allow me to extract this template? I would like to examine and modify the XAML to restyle the toolbar (mostly just change the button label).

I have programmatic access to the template object but I'm not sure how to serialize this into XAML.

Comment: Not an answer, but you may be able to [snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply using [`XamlWriter.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms613434.aspx)?

e.g.

```
var template = control.Template;
using (var stream = new FileStream("template.xaml", FileMode.Create))
{
    using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings() { Indent = true }))
    {
        XamlWriter.Save(template, writer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Very nice try. Unfortunately it barfs with `Cannot serialize a non-public type 'System.Activities.Presentation.Internal.PropertyEditing.KeyboardEnabledRadioButton'.`

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but I think this tells me that the template was created programmatically since it *cannot* be expressed as XAML. I suppose at some point I shall have to write a XamlWriter implementation that ignores protection levels, but ripping templates is not something I often do :).

Comment: What makes you think that it cannot be expressed in XAML?

Comment: Now that you ask the question, it crosses my mind that you simply wouldn't set this particular member with markup. By this logic, XmlWriter should simply ignore such members. It's a pity the source isn't available, it would be so easy to change this behaviour.

Comment: The object in question is not a member but a class, and you *can* use internal classes in XAML, it just does not happen "normally" as VS declates Windows and UserControls to be public by default.

Comment: Are you saying that XmlWriter shouldn't choke on this?

Comment: I am just saying that it is not necessarily impossible to define  a template in XAML which fits the exception that was thrown. The documentation claims that the XamlWriter [has limitations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754193.aspx), while i do not know if this exception fits anything described there this might just be one of those limitations.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried Red Gate's Reflector?  Of course, if the assembly is obfuscated it may not really be of much help.